# Ubuntu 16.04 USB modem detected as CD-ROM. Unable to connect

Tags: networking, 16.04, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I am facing difficulty in installing my USB modem in Ubuntu 16.04. Most of the time I connect my USB broadband modem it is connected as CD-ROM.

What I understood from the web was that `usb-modeswitch` can be used to switch it to a USB device, but its unable to switch it. Even 'Enable Mobile Broadband' option is not shown in network manager (maybe because it is not detected as modem).

Things that I tried to solve this problem with **no luck**:

1. Tried `usb_modeswitch`:

   ```
   $sudo usb_modeswitch -I -W -c 12d1\:1505

   Read config file: 12d1:1505

    * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
    * Version 2.2.5 (C) Josua Dietze 2015
    * Based on libusb1/libusbx

    ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

   DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
   DefaultProduct= 0x1505
   MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
   NeedResponse=0

   InquireDevice=1

   Look for default devices ...
     found USB ID 8087:8001
     found USB ID 1d6b:0002
     found USB ID 1d6b:0003
     found USB ID 05e3:0608
     found USB ID 12d1:1505
      vendor ID matched
      product ID matched
     found USB ID 17ef:600e
     found USB ID 1d6b:0002
    Found devices in default mode (1)
   Access device 012 on bus 002
   Current configuration number is 1
   Use interface number 0
   Use endpoints 0x08 (out) and 0x87 (in)
   Inquire device details; driver will be detached ...
   Looking for active driver ...
    No active driver found. Detached before or never attached

   SCSI inquiry data (for identification)
   -------------------------
     Vendor String: HUAWEI  
      Model String: Mass Storage    
   Revision String: 2.31
   -------------------------

   USB description data (for identification)
   -------------------------
   Manufacturer: HUA?WEI TECHNOLOGIES
        Product: HUAWEI Mobile
     Serial No.: ???????????????????
   -------------------------
   Set up interface 0
   Use endpoint 0x08 for message sending ...
   Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x08 ...
    OK, message successfully sent
   Reset response endpoint 0x87
   Reset message endpoint 0x08
   -> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!

   $sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x1505
   ```
2. Installed `sakis3g` to connect to modem but no luck, it gives error.
3. Downgraded `usb-modemswitch` and `usb-modeswitch-data` to 14.04 version as my modem was working in that version.

`dmesg` output:

```
[ 6720.186115] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from 24:de:c6:92:e6:32 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 6720.385636] userif-2: sent link down event.
[ 6720.385643] userif-2: sent link up event.
[ 6770.784741] userif-2: sent link down event.
[ 6770.784748] userif-2: sent link up event.
[ 6773.520387] wlp4s0: authenticate with 24:de:c6:92:e6:32
[ 6773.526287] wlp4s0: send auth to 24:de:c6:92:e6:32 (try 1/3)
[ 6773.530702] wlp4s0: authenticated
[ 6773.534123] wlp4s0: associate with 24:de:c6:92:e6:32 (try 1/3)
[ 6773.541699] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 24:de:c6:92:e6:32 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 6773.543920] wlp4s0: associated
[ 6773.648434] bridge-enp0s25: disabling the bridge
[ 6773.674082] bridge-enp0s25: down
[ 6773.674088] bridge-enp0s25: detached
[ 6773.674125] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 2607 (vmnet-bridge)
[ 6773.674134] /dev/vmnet: hub 0 does not exist, allocating memory.
[ 6773.674151] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 0 successfully opened
[ 6773.674158] bridge-wlp4s0: device is wireless, enabling SMAC
[ 6773.674160] bridge-wlp4s0: up
[ 6773.674164] bridge-wlp4s0: attached
[ 6773.774151] userif-2: sent link down event.
[ 6773.774154] userif-2: sent link up event.
[ 7128.236448] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Down
[ 7128.436880] userif-2: sent link down event.
[ 7128.436883] userif-2: sent link up event.
[ 8602.833095] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 8602.962666] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1505
[ 8602.962673] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[ 8602.962677] usb 2-4: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[ 8602.962681] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: HUAÿWEI TECHNOLOGIES
[ 8602.962684] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
[ 8602.963681] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 8602.965891] scsi host8: usb-storage 2-4:1.0
[ 8603.967998] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 8603.977960] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[ 8603.978316] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 8603.978518] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 12d1:1505 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 17ef:600e Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`uname -ar` output:

```
Linux 01-Linux 4.4.8-040408-generic #201604200335 SMP Wed Apr 20 07:37:30 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and I have fix it. You need to install the Huawei driver for Ubuntu.

**1) Configuration**
With the result of `lsusb` in the terminal (for me, the pid of my Huawei was `12d1:15d2`, for example) See [thread on ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217416)

**2) Download the drivers :**
 HUAWEI Data Cards Linux (click on Download file).
See [download.usbmodem.com](http://download.myusbmodem.com/download.php?file=/Huawei%20miscellaneous/HUAWEI%20Data%20Cards%20Linux%20Driver.zip&start=1)

**3) Installation**
See [article on modemunlock.com](http://www.modemunlock.com/huawei-linux-driver-download-and-installation.html)

Comment: This is not working as I mentioned in the question that USB Dongle is detected as CD-ROM not as ttyUSB.